# Find the characteristic polynom

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hello I have the following problem :

Let $A_{7x7}$ and also $rank (A) = 4$

$q(t)=t^4-7t^2+10$ is dividing the characteristic polynom of $A$, meaning that exist polynom $s(t) \rightarrow p_a(t)=q(t)s(t)$

Find $p_a(t)$.

That how I solved it, yet for some reason its incorrect.

I know that the $rank(A)=4$ therefore $0$ is eigenvalue algebric multiplexing of $3$, and geometric multiplexing of $n-P(A)=7-4=3$, meaning therefore the algeberic multiplexing equal to the gemetric multiplexing therefore $A$ diagonalizable for eigenvalue $0$.

Therefore $s(t)=t^3$ therfore $P_a(t)=q(t)(s)t \implies P_a(t)=t^3(t^4-7t^2+10)$

In the answer they get $p_a(t)=t^4(t^4-7t^2+10)$

Any ideas what's wrong with solution?

Thank you!

Comment: you right the answer is wrong. Since the matrix is of order $7\times 7$ the characteristic polynomial must be of degree $7$.

Comment: @Ofir Schnabel Are you sure? mathematician doctor has reached to this answer, which makes it more likely that I'm wrong.

Comment: The matrix is $7 \times 7$ so the degree of the characteristic polynomial must be $7$, not $8$ as said in the solution. It is evident that $t^4(t^4-7t^2+10)$ is wrong, unless the matrix is actually $8 \times 8$.

Comment: "Even" mathematician doctor can be wrong.